# C++ : What is happening when a non-overridden calls a overridden method?

Tags: c++, overriding, member-hiding

The version of a overridden method that gets invoked depends on 
if you care calling the function "through" the base class or "through" the derived class.  However, I am finding if I call a non-overridden method, and the overridden method calls some function that *is* overridden, then the base class version is still called, even though I am accessing the instance through pointer to the derived class. Could someone explain why this happens?

CODE:

```
class Base {
public:
    void display() {
        foo();
    }
    void foo() {
        cout << "Base.foo()" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        cout << "Derived.foo()" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived* derived = new Derived();
    derived->display();
    while (true) {}
}
```

Comment: You are not overriding these functions because they are not `virtual`

Answer (score 6):

> the base class version is still called, even though I am accessing the
>   instance through pointer to the derived class. Could someone explain
>   why this happens?

Although you call method via pointer to derived class, your method is not virtual, so static dispatch is used, so `Base::display()` calls `Base::foo()` directly, even if it is overridden in subclasses. To achieve behavior you want, you must use dynamic dispatch, i.e. mark your methods as `virtual`.

```
class Base {
public:
    void display() {
        foo();
        bar();
    }
    void foo() {
        cout << "Base.foo()" << endl;
    }
    virtual void bar() {
        cout << "Base.bar()" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        cout << "Derived.foo()" << endl;
    }
    virtual void bar() {
        cout << "Derived.bar()" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived* derived = new Derived();
    derived->display();
}
```

Output:

```
Base.foo()
Derived.bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is: you do not have overridden any function; you have [hidden its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688799/what-is-the-hiding-rule-in-c).

In C++, only virtual functions (see [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions)) can be overridden. Making the *Base::foo()* virtual yields the expected result: ([run code!](http://ideone.com/7KT11n))

```
class Base {
public:
    void display() {
        foo();
    }
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "Base.foo()" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        cout << "Derived.foo()" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived* derived = new Derived();
    derived->display();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
virtual qualifier needs to be used for methods that need to be overridden.
ex:
 class Base {
public:
    void display() {
        foo();
    }
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "Base.foo()" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "Derived.foo()" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived* derived = new Derived();
    derived->display();
    while (true) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a virtual function.

An object in a class hierarchy has two types: It's "real" class, and the class that the compiler thinks at the moment that it has.

When you call a virtual function, the compiler always calls the function that belongs to the "real" class. When you call a non-virtual function, the compiler calls the function belong to the class that it *thinks* is the objects class.

While executing code in a subclass, the compiler thinks that *this is an object of the subclass. Therefore calling a non-virtual function will call the function belonging to that subclass.